# antonym of "privacy"

Tags: antonyms

It seems to me that "transparency" can be considered to be an antonym of "privacy".  This isn't symmetric.  Because few people would think of "privacy" as an antonym of "transparency".  So where does the symmetry break down?

**Edit:**  since the question is attracting some answers which address the title of the question, but are skipping the content of the question, I'll add an emphasis.

**Emphasis**:  I am specifically asking "**why does the symmetry break down**?" *Transparency* is an antonym of *privacy* while *privacy* is **not** an antonym of *transparency*.

I freely admit that both terms have a lot of controversial uses attached to them.  Most of the controversy is around where the boundaries of the terms lie and where they "*should*" lie.  But in their basic usage, the lack of symmetry remains.

Comment: How about "openness" or (choke) "publicness".  And of course there's "publicity".

Comment: Yeah, or broad-daylightedness.

Comment: Does it have to be a single word?

Comment: It breaks down because _transparency_ has an exact antonym: **opacity**    http://www.google.com/search?q=opaque     http://www.google.com/search?q=opacity

Comment: Privacy has several nuances, from doors on restroom stalls, to Bill of Rights search-and-seizure protections, to whether or not Facebook should share your buying habits or exact physical location with the rest of the world. In some senses, _intrusion_ or _invasion (of privacy)_ are apt (**invasion of privacy** is a set phrase.)  But the least "loaded" antonym is _lack of privacy_. Sorry.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock, I believe transparency of congregated information and its availability (to those who are entitled to see the comprising pieces of information) was one of the ways FB was promoting itself.  So, in that sense, they made the choice of "transparency" as an antonym of privacy consciously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetry breaks down because there are multiple meanings of the word *privacy*. Depending on the nuance required, various antonyms are appropriate.

It is not uncommon in English to have words that do not have a single, exact, precise antonym. We all learned the easy ones: big/small, wet/dry. But words like *privacy* have too many shades of meaning to have a single antonym.

The best antonyms, depending on how the word *privacy* is used, are probably:

- publicity
- transparency
- openness

Answer (score 0):

Probably ***[publicity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/publicity)*** with the following connotation, conveys the meaning you are looking for:

> - Information about someone or something that is disseminated through various media to attract public notice: *The publicity that went out about the film was not very exciting.*

(AHD)

Comment: Privacy, even in its most straight-forward meaning, is more than just lack of publicity.